# Google places autocomplete for ios not working 100% of the time

Tags: ios, google-places

Google places autocomplete is working sporadically. We are not anywhere near reaching the maximum quota 201 requests, and with no errors showing.

Knowing that google places autocomplete was previously working perfectly fine and that we haven't made any changes in the past few weeks.Now, it seems like more of a luck thing with 30% chance of working and 70% not.
[image]

Comment: Now, it's randomly working again, but still don't know what caused the problem. I reached out to customer support for google places autocomplete and I am still waiting for their answer as I want to know what may have happened, so it could be avoided in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version that you are using, maybe you are using an unsupported version.

> **Notice**: Version 2.7.0 of the Places SDK for iOS is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019. A new version of the Places SDK for iOS is now available. We recommend updating to the new version as soon as possible. For details, see the migration guide. [See Source link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/intro)

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete) to follow in order to setup the API correctly (*following your needs*)

Also, if you will be using the version 3+ take a look at this [reminder](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration):

> **Reminder**: To use the Places SDK for iOS, you must:
>
> - Include an API key with all API requests.
> - Enable billing on each of your projects.
> - Enable the Places API service for each of your projects.

Hope this will solve your issue you ;)